# correct file encoding after loading data from database into R

Tags: mysql, r, database, utf-8

I am learning how to import data from database into R.
I have used the following code:

```
library("RMySQL")
library("dbConnect")

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "database_name",host = "xyz.amazonaws.com",user="xxxxxxx",password="ghujkfgd")
dbListTables(con)

df <- "CALL get_transactions('all');"
df <- dbGetQuery(con, df)
```

but the data in having some encoding problem:

> [image: enter code here]

The left hand side column is the column I am exporting from database and right hand side column is the original column. Can someone tell me how I can I read data with accents or special characters from database to R. TIA.

Comment: It looks as though the data was encoded in Latin1, but it's not clear from your posting what you have now.  For example, in the first `email` value, is `<ed>` a single character printed in an ugly format, or is it 4 characters?  What is it in the database you're reading from?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using the following code:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "database_name",host = "xyz.amazonaws.com",user="xxxxxxx",password="ghujkfgd"
dbListTables(con)

df <- "CALL get_transactions('all');"
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, df)
data <- fetch(rs, n= -1)


dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

`edf3c1e1f1fa` are the hex codes for `íóÁáñú` in `CHARACTER SET latin1`.

Probably something was expecting `UTF-8` (`CHARACTER SET utf8` or `utf8mb4`) and croaked on `ed`, hence said `Roc<ed>ghf` instead of `Rocíghf`.

My notes on `R` say

```
Tool -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving and put UTF-8

rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```

options(encoding = "UTF-8") at the top of my main script from which the package is called.

However, this *may* happen to be backwards, and you may need to use `latin1` instead of `utf8`.